# Securing Asp.net Web Form Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can any one let me know what are the various methods of adding security to asp.net application. for example how we can protect the web.config file that contains the database connection information or how we can generally protect our web.config file.

Are their any methods or features like using cryptography or something else to protect our application or we can add any additional security to our application.

Comment: apparently you did not have make any research on that topic because there are already too many tutorials.

Comment: What level of security you wish for the web config.. there is some already in place for it..

Answer (score 0):

.config files are, by default, not served by IIS so in that regard you don't have to do anything.

As far as encrypting the connection string, ASP.NET provides that for you out of the box. Read this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(v=vs.80).aspx